# mips printing numbers with # of bits given in input

Tags: mips, mars-simulator

I need to make a mips program that when given an integer, will print all possible numbers with that number of bits. What is the best was to do this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: You need an algorithm.  Most all algorithms are language independent.  So, you don't need think in assembly to get an algorithm, and you don't need to research only for a MIPS version of this algorithm.  Reduce the complexity of the problem by separating getting an algorithm working from doing that same algorithm in MIPS assembly.

Answer (score 0):

This might help get you started. It's a way to count the number of 1s in a binary number.

```
popcnt:
;input: $a0 = the 32-bit number you wish to check
;output: $v0 = the number of bits that equal 1.

move $v0,$zero
li $t0,32

loop_popcnt:

move $a1,$a0
andi $a1,$a1,1
beqz $a1,skip    # if zero, the bit we tested was zero, so don't add 1 to the answer.
   nop           # branch delay slot. We don't want the next instruction to execute if we branch

   addiu $v0,$v0,1
skip:

ror $a0,$a0,1    # next bit
addiu $t0,$t0,-1 

bnez $t0,loop_popcnt
nop              #branch delay slot.

jr $ra
```